# Spotfire non-editable button

Tags: spotfire, spotfire-analyst, spotfire-webplayer

I am sort of new to Spotfire. There is feedback button in a dashboard I am working on, and I am trying to edit that button, but I can't find the option anywhere. The button also gets created automatically when a new page is created. Is there something I am missing?  Has anyone encountered this? Any help would be

I tried to edit the HTML but there is no option for this particular button.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) You should not just request a ready solution. SO is for helping solve specific errors, after you've shown your effort solving them

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Is the button in a Text Area? If you edit the Text Area you should be able to edit the button. The main reasons why a button is greyed out in my experience is that it refers to an invalid 'action'. For instance, the button navigates to a page that no longer exists, or the button points to a script where the input parameters are not set, or the button launches a data function that is updated automatically. You need to be able to edit to find out.